# An example of the quotient of definable groups not being definable?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

In my quest to understand interpretability and Shelah's $(-)^{\text{eq}}$ construction, I stumbled upon the following remark in page 29 of Marker's *Model Theory*:

> Suppose that we have a definable group $G$ and a definable normal subgroup $H$. We might want to look at the group $G/H$. It is possible that $G/H$ does not correspond to a definable group in our structure.

After looking around for some time, I have not found a concrete example which realises the latter sentence of the statement above, and I am struggling to come up with such an example myself. So far I've been able to understand most of the theory surrouding interpretability and the $(-)^{\text{eq}}$ construction together with the provided examples, but it seems that any possible example of a quotient of definable groups not being definable is trying to hide from me.

I'm pretty sure such an example doesn't have to by anything fancy, and my bet is that such quotient not being definable will have to do about its universe not being a subset of any power of the universe of the original definable group.

Any idea is much appreciated!

---

**Edit:** I just realised that instead of asking for a particular example, a more interesting question would be:

> Under which conditions the quotient of definable groups is definable?

This seems (at least to my newbie model-theoretic eyes) a highly non-trivial question, and I'm afraid that even if an answer is given to this I will probably not be able to follow it. However, if anoyone could shed some light on this last question it would be nice too, of course.

Comment: It seems to me that the condition you're looking for post-edit is precisely *elimination of imaginaries*. The main property that the ^eq construction gives us is precisely that.

Comment: @Z.A.K. Certainly elimination of imaginaries implies that every quotient of definable groups is definable. But it's possible that a theory may fail to have elimination of imaginaries, but still define quotients of definable groups (for example, this can happen vacuously, if the theory does not define any infinite groups!).

Comment: @Z.A.K. Aaah my friend, I see; I rushed the question before seeing how this connects with EI... Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @AlexKruckman And thanks for pointing out that EI  just gives you one direction :)

Comment: @Z.A.K. By the way, although it is not related to this post, I want to answer a question you asked me some time ago, before I forget about it. *Every* regular category arises as the syntactic category of some regular theory, namely it's own internal theory. In other words, $\mathcal{C} \cong \mathcal{C}_{\mathbb{T}_{\mathcal{C}}}$ for every regular category $\mathcal{C}$, where $\cong$ means equivalence, not isomorphism of course (damn, now you know I'm not Spiderman...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erik Walsberg told me the following example:

Consider the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$. The ring of $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is definable in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, so the multiplicative group of units $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ is a definable subgroup of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$. The quotient $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times/\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ (this is the value group of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, viewed as a valued field). But no group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ is definable in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, since every definable subset of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is finite or has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.